# how to access `split' function results to compare strings in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, crash

I have CSV file that i convert to an excel file that has two tabs, each with a column of zip codes.  the property i'm trying to see if the property zip codes are anywhere in the list of property zip codes.  The property zip codes are in comma separated lists in the individual cells of the property tab.

I'm getting there, but what I have crashes the system.  Can anyone tell me why?

Here's my code:

```
Sub propZips()
Dim wsProperty As Worksheet:              Set wsProperty = Worksheets("propertyOutput.csv")
Dim zipColumnProperty As Integer:       zipColumnProperty = 2
Dim propertyRows As Integer:               propertyRows = wsProperty.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1  ' less 1 for label row
Dim singlePropZip As String

' vendor variables
Dim wsVendor As Worksheet:                Set wsVendor = Worksheets("vendorOutput.csv")
Dim zipColumnVendor As Integer:         zipColumnVendor = 5
Dim vendorRows As Integer:                   vendorRows = wsVendor.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1 ' less 1 for label row

' counter variables
Dim propCounter As Integer ' for loop through property zips
Dim venCounter As Integer '  for loop through vendors

Dim tempServArea() As String ' array to hold an individul vendor's service area
Dim subArrayCounter As Integer

    For propCounter = 1 To propertyRows  ' loop through properties
        singlePropZip = wsProperty.Cells(propCounter + 1, zipColumnProperty) ' propety zip in question
        For venCounter = 1 To vendorRows ' loop through vendor service areas
             tempServArea = Split(wsVendor.Cells(venCounter + 1, zipColumnVendor), ",") ' load temp array with split reults
             For subArrayCounter = 1 To UBound(tempServArea) ' loop through indivudula vendor service area
                    Debug.Print "ubound of tempServArea is:" & UBound(tempServArea)                               
             Next subArrayCounter

        Next venCounter ' end loop through service areas
    Next propCounter ' end loop through properties
End Sub
```

Ultimately, I want to run a report that tells me which zip codes are missing a vendor.  Obviously, I'm  not finished.  I'm hoping to compare the string in the last `for` loop, but, as I said, i'm crashing the program and I don't know why.

Comment: If your list of zip codes on the property sheet is one zip code per cell, just loop through that list using the Find method on the vendor zip column (with xlPart argument), to determine if the zip code is assigned to a vendor.

Comment: Thanks!  Will that allow me to get info from the row where the zip code exists?  Ie will it tell me where I find the zip in question?

Comment: Yes. The Find method will return the cell containing the zip code on the vendor sheet; once you know that, you should be able to get info from any other related cell.